# How to re-use the classes of an Integration Test in other ITs?

Tags: maven

I have several Integration Tests in my maven project that have common classes that I duplicate from one IT to another, it is obvious that it is not a clean way to do it. So I would like to know if there is a way to reuse the classes of given IT in other ITs.

So far as the artifacts of my ITs are not published in my local repository the only way I found is to move the common classes in my main classes but it is still quite ugly as I mixed main classes with test classes just to avoid duplicating test code.

Here is my project structure:

```
resources
src
└── it
|   └── it1
|   |   └── src
|   |       └── main
|   └── it2
|   |   └── src
|   |        └── main
... ...
└── main
    └── java
    └── resources
    test
    └── java
    └── resources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to create a new common integration test that will do nothing except containing the common classes. You can [prepare the build environment](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/prepare-build-env.html) to be sure that the common IT test is executed and installed in the local repository before the others with the [`setupIncludes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#setupIncludes) parameter.

> In general, the plugin assumes that the projects to build are unrelated to one other such that their build order does not matter. However, you might sometimes want to ensure that certain projects are build before others. As a motivation, imagine that a project performs some kind of common setup for the other projects, e.g. installing utility artifacts into the local repository.

By default, this matches any project named `setup*/pom.xml`, so we can name it `setup-its`:

```
src
+--it
    +--setup-its
        +--invoker.properties
        +--pom.xml
    +--it1
        +--pom.xml
    +--it2
        +--pom.xml
```

The `setup-its` project will contain the common classes. You can tell the `maven-invoker-plugin`, that is used to launch the integration tests, to install it into your local repository with the following `invoker.properties` ([`invokerPropertiesFile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#invokerPropertiesFile)):

```
invoker.goals = clean install
```

Then, you can depend on this artifact in the other ITs like you would for any artifacts.

#### Example of `setup-its`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>setup-its</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

#### Example of `it1`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>it1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>setup-its</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This approach works well when there is a single project that sets-up the environment for the rest. If you need to control the build order further, you will have to rely on making a multi-module project with intra-dependencies.